# Sending files as attachment to self - error Account {path} does not exist

Tags: bash, shell

We are using a script to send log files from the server to my own email address. Somehow this is not working and the error I get is "Account {path} does not exist." ... somehow it is not resolving the path to attach the files using -A?

How can I send this file as attachment through shell

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    echo "[Error] Email missing, use as sendlogs.sh [email]"
    exit
fi

# Absolute path to this script, e.g. /home/user/bin/foo.sh
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f "$0")

# Absolute path this script is in, thus /home/user/bin
SCRIPTPATH=$(dirname "$SCRIPT")

LOGDIR="$SCRIPTPATH/../etc/logs"

zip $LOGDIR/logs.zip $LOGDIR/log_error.log $LOGDIR/log_info.log

echo "Crawler logs from server" | mail -s "Crawler logs from server" -A "$LOGDIR/logs.zip" "$1"

rm -f $LOGDIR/logs.zip

echo "Email sent to $1 with logs"
```

---

```
sendlogs.sh email@mail.com
updating: var/www/html/user/scrapy/subdir/../etc/logs/log_error.log (deflated 99%)
updating: var/www/html/user/scrapy/subdir/../etc/logs/log_info.log (deflated 68%)
Account /var/www/html/user/scrapy/subdir/../etc/logs/logs.zip does not exist.
Email sent to email@mail.com with logs
```

`Mail -V` gives "`12.5 7/5/10`"

`readlink -f $(which mail)` gives `/usr/bin/mailx`

And `man mailx`

```
NAME
       mailx - send and receive Internet mail

SYNOPSIS
       mailx [-BDdEFintv~] [-s subject] [-a attachment ] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] [-r from-addr] [-h hops] [-A account] [-S variable[=value]] to-addr . . .
       mailx [-BDdeEHiInNRv~] [-T name] [-A account] [-S variable[=value]] -f [name]
       mailx [-BDdeEinNRv~] [-A account] [-S variable[=value]] [-u user]

DESCRIPTION
       Mailx  is  an intelligent mail processing system, which has a command syntax reminiscent of ed(1) with lines replaced by messages.  It is based on Berkeley Mail 8.1, is intended
       to provide the functionality of the POSIX mailx command, and offers extensions for MIME, IMAP, POP3, SMTP, and S/MIME.  Mailx provides enhanced  features  for  interactive  use,
       such as caching and disconnected operation for IMAP, message threading, scoring, and filtering.  It is also usable as a mail batch language, both for sending and receiving mail.

       The following options are accepted:

       -A name
              Executes an account command (see below) for name after the startup files have been read.

       -a file
              Attach the given file to the message.

       -B     Make standard input and standard output line-buffered.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your version of `mail` is actually BSD's `s-nail`. You can check with `man mail` or `which mail` etc.

For `s-nail`, use `-a` instead of `-A`.

GNU mail, from GNU mailutils, as for example in Debian uses `-A` for attachments:

> ```
> -A, --attach=FILE
>     attach FILE
>
> -a, --append=HEADER: VALUE append given header to the message being sent
> ```

But `s-nail` as for example in Ubuntu, uses `-a` :

> ```
> -A account  Executes an account command (see below) for account ...
>
> -a file     Attach the given file to the message.  ...
> ```

You can probably check the options with

```
mail --help
```

And you can check what `mail`really is on your system with command like

```
which mail
readlink -f $(which mail)
```

and/or maybe get the version with

```
mail -V
```

Comment: See the error message maybe it is something with the path? It contains double dots .... ? Also it warns about a non existent account

Comment: The error seems to point to an expected "Account" after the `-A` option.

Comment: And I get exactly the same error on Ubuntu where `mail` is really `/usr/bin/s-nail`.

Comment: I updated the command to mailx instead of mail (which is strange because mail = mailx) and added the -a command instead of -A .... now I see correct logging ... but alas! the email never arrives ;)

Comment: Then look at `/var/log/mail.log` or `/var/log/maillog` or whatever it is on your system.